# Doctrine doesn't generate inherited-class's properties

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have one abstract MappedSuperClass and another class called "User" which is a child of this MappedSuperClass. The problem is that doctrine doesn't generate the User class's properties. Only the MappedSuperClass's properties. Why?

```
<?php
namespace IsCoconut\Models;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;


/** @MappedSuperclass */
abstract class BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id 
     * @Column(type="integer") 
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="boolean")
     *  @var boolean
     */
    protected $deleted = false;

    /** @Column(name="creation_date_time", type="datetime")
     *  @var DateTime
     */
    protected $creationDateTime;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        $this->creationDateTime = new DateTime();
    }
}
```

And this is my Entity which should be generated in database by Doctrine

```
<?php
namespace IsCoconut\Models;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512)
     */
    private $forename;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=512, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    private $passwordHash;
}
```

This is output of `doctrine orm:schema-tool:create --dump-sql`

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INT NOT NULL, deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL, creation_date_time TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE SEQUENCE users_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
```

**The User's class entity properties are missing!** Why?

Comment: What happens if you make the properties `protected`?

Comment: Nothing at all. I have already tried that

Comment: What are your "use" statements in the User class file?

Comment: use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;

Comment: I also notice in the User class file you have `@ORM\Column'... Maybe you should change everything to `@ORM` to make it consistent? There could be a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I removed all `@ORM\` prefixes, it works now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="User")
```

Comment: This didn't help as well

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this might be the solution:

change:

```
abstract class BaseEntity
```

to:

```
class BaseEntity
```

See if that works. It might not, please try it.

Comment: Did you also change in the User class `@Entity` to `@ORM\Entity`?

Comment: Yes, I did but It's not necessary because of `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found it was due to properties set as private.

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
class BaseClass
{

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $channel;
    //private $channel;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapping on your abstract class should be `* @ORM\MappedSuperclass` not `/** @MappedSuperclass */`. The mapping is done by Doctrine so the ORM annotation is important here.
You also need to ensure your properties in your abstract class are `protected` (which you already said they were)